# Posicionar texto css y mantener proporciones en distintas resoluciones

Tags: html, css, position

> Tengo el código que se presenta abajo, lo que quiero hacer es que la caja de la derecha mida lo mismo que la primera (en altura), y que los textos de ambas se encuentren pegadas al `bottom` de su respectiva caja.

NOTA: Este código, en mi proyecto, se encuentra dentro de la etiqueta `<header>`, y en el navegador yo veo las cajas del mismo tamaño. No entiendo porque en el snippet de S.O. se ve una mas grande que la otra. En mi caso las veo iguales, pero no puedo ajustar el texto abajo.

LO QUE INTENTÉ: Poner a las cajas de afuera `position: relative` y a la de adentro `absoluta; bottom:0px`, en parte funciona pero me tira una caja encima de la otra y no es lo que busco.

Y SI SE PUEDE:
Además de eso, me gustaría que las proporciones de la distancia entre caja y caja se mantengan cuando se cambia de resolución. En mi caso tengo un monitor conectado con una resolución de 1280x720 y la pantalla de la note en 1920x1080, y cuando arrastro el navegador de un monitor al otro las distancias no se respetan.

```css
.filter-content {
    margin-left: 1vw;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 80%;
}

.logo-holder {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    font-family: 'century';
    font-size: 2.7em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 80%;
}
```

```html
            <div class="logo-holder">
                <div style="">
                    textodellogo
                </div>
            </div>

           
            <div class="filter-content">
                <div class="gallery-filters">
                     <a href="#" style="color:#bbbbbb; margin-right: 1em;" data-filter=".nature">beauty</a>
                <a href="#" style="color:#bbbbbb" data-filter=".models">fashion</a>
</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Cajas del mismo tamaño y texto centrado verticalmente al medio?

Comment: el texto posicionado abajo del todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considero que:

- Perfectamente podemos incluir a flexbox para el acomodo general (si de nuevo con el...)
- Envolvemos a las 2 *cajas* en un contenedor general y a este la damos un **`display: flex;`** con lo cual podemos moverlos sobre el eje horizontal
- A los contenedores internos es decir a las 2 cajas, les podemos aplicar:

  - Un alto con con respecto del *viewport* disponible por ejemplo **`80`**
  - Cambiamos la alineación de horizontal a vertical con **`flex-direction`** indicando que ahora será de tipo columna para que queden uno sobre otro (los textos)
  - Para mover los textos al fondo de cada una de sus cajas contenedoras hacemos uso de **`justify-content`** con un valor de **`flex-end`**

**Importante**

Si no deseas que el contenedor de las 2 cajas abarque el 100% de la página entonces puedes hacer estas modificaciones:

- Establece un **`width`** personalizado por ejemplo de **`50vw`**
- Si no deseas que las cajas tengan un espacio entre ellas puedes quitarle el **`justify-content`** y que se acomoden a la izquierda

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      .contenedor-general {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        border: 1px solid;
      }
      .logo-holder,
      .filter-content {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        height: 80vh;  
      }
    </style>
    <div class="contenedor-general">
                  <div class="logo-holder">
                    <div style="">
                        textodellogo
                    </div>
                </div>
    
               
                <div class="filter-content">
                    <div class="gallery-filters">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery-filter" style="color:#bbbbbb; margin-right: 1em;" data-                          filter=".nature">beauty</a>
                        <a href="#" class="gallery-filter" style="color:#bbbbbb" data-                                              filter=".m odels">fashion</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias! Anduvo a la perfeccion! Ahora, te hago una consulta. Si yo tuviera un tercer div, que quiero ponerlo dentro de este ``contenedor-principal`` y tirarlo hacia la derecha, que tendria que usar en reemplazo de ``float:right`` (ya que no hace nada cuando le doy ese valor. Probe tambien un width:100% con margin-right: 0 y no funcionó. Gracias

Comment: es decir: 2 divs a la izquierda y el otro a la derecha?

Comment: ya lo solucioné.Gracias de todos modos!